# when i clicked on two imageviews which are overlapped, one of them gives me feedback the other does not

Tags: java, android, arrays

Here is codes, and i am trying to receive a feedback from imageviews which are overlapped. One of the imageviews return isPressed method true, but the other one return me false. They are overlapped, so when i clicked one of them, both of their isPressed method should be true, i guess. Where am i wrong

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

  ImageView[] imageViews;
  Button button;
  int a = 0;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridLayout gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);

    GridLayout.LayoutParams[] layoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams[9];
    imageViews = new ImageView[18];

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = -1, m = 0; j < 3 & k < 3 & m < imageViews.length || i < layoutParams.length; m++) {

        if (m == 18) {
            break;
        }

        if (m == 0) {
            k++;
        }

        layoutParams[i] = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        layoutParams[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layoutParams[i].setMargins(25, 25, 25, 25);
        layoutParams[i].columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(k, GridLayout.CENTER);
        layoutParams[i].rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(j, GridLayout.CENTER);

        imageViews[m] = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        imageViews[m].setLayoutParams(layoutParams[i]);
        gridLayout.addView(imageViews[m]); //---

        if (m % 2 == 0) {
            imageViews[m].setImageResource(R.drawable.first_image);
            imageViews[m].setAlpha(1f);
        } else {
            imageViews[m].setImageResource(R.drawable.second_image);
            imageViews[m].setAlpha(0.5f);
        }

        if (m % 2 == 1 & m != 0) {
            j++;
            i++;
        }
        if (m % 6 == 5 & m != 0) {
            k++;
        }
        if (j == 3) {
            j = 0;
        }
    }

    actionView();

  }

  public void actionView() {

    for (int m = 0; m < imageViews.length; m++) {

        imageViews[m].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "  " + a + "  " + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG, imageViews[1].isPressed() + "");
                Log.e(TAG, imageViews[0].isPressed() + "");
                Log.e(TAG, imageViews[1].isEnabled() + "");
                Log.e(TAG, imageViews[0].isEnabled() + "");
                Log.e(TAG, "--------------------");
                a++;

                for (int x = 0; x < imageViews.length; x++) {
                    if (imageViews[x].isPressed()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, x + " Image is clicked");
                        Log.e(TAG, " *****************");
                    }
                }


            }
        });
    }


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            a = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: *both of their isPressed method should be true, i guess.* I guess your guess is wrong.

Comment: No, only the view which is on top will receive the onClick event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the views are overlapped and click is enabled for both only the view on top will receive the click event.

If you want to call on click event of both, call performClick of the view in background form the onclick listener of the view in front.

Like imageviewInBack.performClick()